# youtube iframe embeding it doesnt work when I want autoplay and loop to work but no control to show

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, autoplay

I have the following code and need to autoplay my video in my website. but it doesnt autoplay, nor it loops the video with no control.

```
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3fRxOjkik0g?autoplay=1&loop=1&showinfo=0&controls=0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Autoplay is no longer allowed without user input - so I imagine that's why.

You can read more here:

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

It has to be muted if you want to autoplay.

A user has to interact with the div for it to start playing.

Comment: yes, it had to be muted

Answer (score 1):

To **autoplay** the video you will need to mute your video as **@polisen** already mentioned. But I want to say that to **loop** a YouTube embed Video you will need a **playlist** to be mentioned in the Embed URL and in case you do not have a playlist you can use the **Video Id** as your **Playlist Id**.